# NPAPI plugin can work on mac10.8 but not mac10.6

Tags: macos, npapi, browser-plugin

I develop a npapi plugin on mac10.8 with xcode4.5 and the Gecko SDK is Gecko 17.0(mac i386).
The plugin can work on mac10.8 but not mac10.6,I don't what problem with it。somebody can tell me what can i do and how to solve the problem.The plugin on mac10.6 only safari can find the MIME type and other browser can't find the MIME type,but the plugin can't work on safari.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue is that you built it using the Mac OS 10.8 sdk; to target 10.6 ideally you want to build it using the 10.6 SDK (which you may have to go find), but you could try just setting the deployment target to 10.6 and it *might* work.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a 64-bit or 32-bit build? In Mac 10.6 some browsers are looking for 64-bit version and some others want 32-bit. It may help if you include both builds in your bundle.

Comment: I'm not aware of any browsers that are different between 10.6 and 10.8 in terms of what architecture of plugins they prefer.

Comment: I have a dual 32/64 built plugin on my Mac 10.6.8; Safari and Firefox prefer 64-bit version, Chrome, Opera and Camino prefer 32-bit version. Unfortunately, I don't have Mac 10.8